# How to run Specflow test cases in pipeline of Gitlab for CI/CD implementaiton

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to implement CI/CD so that whenever dev team commits any changes in their build then my whole automation suite runs before build and deployment.

**I have yml file in GitLab and automated test case scripts in Visual Studio (Specflow framework in C#).**

Please find below yml file:

```
demo_job_1:
     stage: test
     tags:
       - win
     script: 
       - echo "Test 1 started"
       - '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe /ProjName.dll"'
       - '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\MSTest /testcontainer:D:\Users\username\source\repos\Project\ProjName\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ProjName.dll"'
       - "D:\Users\username\source\repos\Project\ProjName\ProjName.sln\Test\TestFeature1.csproj"'
```

But my job is passing without actually executing any of the test cases from the project

Folder structure in Visual studio:
[image]

I tried to do many changes in the path but none worked. Am I entering the wrong path? Can anyone please help me with this? If the yml file is completely wrong then can someone please guide me in the same? Thanks in advance!!! :)

P.S: I had validated yml before committing it and ymlvalidator showed it as the correct yml file.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Hi, in your script i see path "C:". The file you want to execute have to be in the repository git. And to have Visual Studio context, you have to specify an associate image

Comment: Thankyou @Jean-Phi Baconnais for guiding me. After a searching more I have finally found solution, which I am posting below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
demo_job_1:
     stage: test

     tags:
       - tags
       
       
     script:
       - Root dir location path
       - 'dotnet restore <path to the ProjName.sln>'
       - 'dotnet msbuild <path to the ProjName.sln>'
       - 'dotnet test <path to the ProjName.sln>'
```

Hope this helps others too!!!